# Add rows from CSV with duplicate values in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, csv

Using Papaparse, I am trying to add together rows with a duplicate SKU.  I am trying to do this without adding another JS library like D3.
My CSV looks like this:

```
SKU,Daily total,Weekly total
AAA111,2,10
BBB222,4,6
CCC333,11,19
AAA111,5,11
BBB222,6,12
```

I have it output all the rows from the table, but I need to dynamically add all the rows with the same SKU number together.

```
    <script>
        function datasetToMap(data) {
        var ret = {};
        $(data).each(function(index, row) {
            ret[row] = row;
        });
           
    return ret;
}

function appendMapToTable(map) {
    var $table = $('#my-table');
    Object.keys(map).forEach(function(key, i) {
        var rowData = map[key];
          var row = $('<tr class="rownum-' + [i] + '"></tr>');
      $(rowData).each(function (j, cellData) {
        row.append($('<td class="' + [j] + '">'+ cellData +'</td>'));
    });
      $table.append(row);
  });
}

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0453/8489/t/26/assets/testcsv.csv",
    success: function (data) {
        appendMapToTable(datasetToMap(Papa.parse(data).data));
    }
});
```

I am trying to get AAA1111 to have a count of 7 and 21, and BBB222 to have a count of 10 and 18 in the table.

I have a working example here: https://codepen.io/BIGREDBOOTS/pen/LjmojW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an ES6 solution that uses a hash to store SKU and a reduce operation to aggregate the day and week totals:

```js
const data = `SKU,Daily total,Weekly total
AAA111,2,10
BBB222,4,6
CCC333,11,19
AAA111,5,11
BBB222,6,12`

// remove the header row and parse numbers
const rows = data.split('\n').slice(1).map((row) => { 
   return row.split(',').map(i => !isNaN(Number(i)) ? Number(i) : i)
})

const aggregate = rows.reduce((p, row) => {
  let [sku, dayTotal, weekTotal] = row
  if (p[sku]) {
    let [_, prevDayTotal, prevWeekTotal] = p[sku]
    p[sku] = [sku, prevDayTotal + dayTotal, prevWeekTotal + weekTotal]
  } else {
    p[sku] = [sku, dayTotal, weekTotal]
  }
  return p
}, {})

console.log(aggregate)
```